# How do I get the name of a Perl module from one of its subroutines?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Let's say I have a Perl module `My::Module`:

```
package My::Module;

sub foo {
   return $module_name;
}
```

What would I replace `$module_name` with to get `My::Module`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
package My::Module;

sub foo {
   return __PACKAGE__;
}
```

[UPDATE] The following might be what you are looking for:

```
package My::Module;

sub new {
    my $self = {};
    bless $self;
    return $self;
}

sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
    return (caller(0))[3];
}

1;


# test 1: calling foo directly.
print "1: ", My::Module::foo, "\n";
# test 2:  instantiating object, then calling method of object instance.
my $x = My::Module->new;
print "2: ", $x->foo(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl
1: My::Module::foo
2: My::Module::foo
```

Comment: You answered it perfectly, but I forgot I needed the subroutine on there as well. Could you add that for me?

Comment: I decided to write another function to report names `sub WhoAmI { return (caller(1))[3]; }`

Comment: Eric: `caller` will only work if the sub was called by another sub in the same package. If it's called by code in a different package, `caller` will return that name. If you want code to have access to the name of the package that code belongs to, just use `__PACKAGE__`. That's what it's there for and no call to any sub is needed.

Comment: @DaveSherohman - I agree, but I need `My::Module::foo`. So either I write `__PACKAGE__.'::foo'` every time. Or I can call `WhoAmI()`, which returns the previous subroutines name with a `(caller(1))[3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at special constant __PACKAGE__.
That may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are trying to just get the name of the script you are in:

```
my $bname=`basename $0`;

print "\n".$bname;
```

Comment: I believe that would get Module.pm, but let me put together a test

Comment: ...and, because it gets the name of the script (i.e., the command line typed by the user) it will never return the name of a `use`d or `require`d module.